# Vuejs - Multiple components use same mixin (only last one gets fired)

Tags: node.js, mixins, webpack, vue.js

I have around four components using the same mixin that I created. In order to get the dimensions of `this.$el` (the CORRECT ones), I had to implement `window.onload = function()` mixin. My mixin looks like this:

```
module.exports = {
    methods: {
        onPageload: function( callback ) {
            window.onload = function() {
                callback();
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Very simple. However, more than one component uses it. I'm creating a slideshow. My Slides component uses it, my Slide component, my Thumb component, and my overall Slider component.
HOWEVER only the very last one to `compile` fires it.

```
var pageLoad = require('../../mixins/Pageload');

module.exports = {
    template: require('./templates/thumbs.html'),

    replace: true,

    data: function() {
        return {
            style: {
                width: 800
            },
            count: 2
        }
    },

    computed: {
        styles: function() {
            return {
                width: this.style.width + 'px'
            }
        }
    },

    mixins: [pageLoad],

    props: ['count'],

    attached: function() {
        this.onPageload( this.setDimensions );
    },

    methods: {
        // Set dimensions for the first time
        setDimensions: function() {
            console.log('setting thumb');
            this.style.width = this.$parent.slideWidth;
        }
    }
};
```

My other "parent" components do the same thing to set their dimensions. This is the MOST inner child of the entire thing.. it's the ONLY one that fires. If I erase it from here, the next child up is the only one that fires. They are overwriting each other in a way. My vue instance is here:

```
new Vue({
    el: '#slideshow',

    components: {
        'sliderarrows': require('../../components/slider/SliderArrows'),
        'sliderthumb': require('../../components/slider/SliderThumb'),
        'sliderslide': require('../../components/slider/SliderSlide'),
        'slides': require('../../components/slider/SliderSlides'),
        'slider': require('../../components/slider/Slider'),
        'thumbnails': require('../../components/slider/SliderThumbs')
    }
});
```

So the thumbnails component is the only one that's firing the mixin method. I feel like it's something to do with the whole compilation of `require()` but I'm not sure since I'm not that familiar with the Node.js module format.

Thanks for any help on how to get this to work!

Answer (score 1):

I had to change my mixin to this:

```
module.exports = {
    methods: {
        onPageload: function( callback ) {
            window.onload = callback();
        }
    }
};
```

It was something with the window.onload opening a new function.